# Can you assign multiple variables at once in PHP like you can with Java?

Tags: php, variables

I want to create 5 variables of type array all at once. Is this possible? In Java I know you can, but can't find anything about PHP. I'd like to do something like this:

```
$var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5 = array();
```

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257131/multiple-variable-assignment)

Comment: @DavidThomas It wouldn't have worked.

Comment: Just to add on to the answers, if you do this with arrays, each variable will be *distinct* arrays that have been initialized to the same thing, not references to the same single array. [An example](http://codepad.org/5FQHs3N0)

Comment: @DavidThomas Yes, I tried this and it didn't work.

Comment: "I'd like to do something like this" is not very precise. Do you want $var1 to equal the first array element, $var2 the second, etc.?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Yes, you can.

```
$a = $b = $c = $d = array();
```

Comment: FWIW, in any language *except* PHP, the result would be multiple variables referring to the *same* array. That is, altering the array in one variable would also alter the array in the other variables. In PHP, because an array assignment does "copy by value" (unless the "reference operator" is used), this does what OP asks - it creates 4 array values, one per variable. [I mention this, so anyone who works in multiple languages will think carefully about what is happening, especially if they use this syntax in different languages.]

Comment: this answer is wrong. The result here is: All these vars gets the same value (that equals to `array()`). Th e solution is using of the `list()`. S. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50984039/2019043).

Comment: I think you need to read the question again.

Answer (score 43):

Since PHP 7.1 you can use **square bracket syntax**:

```
[$var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5] = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

[1] https://wiki.php.net/rfc/short_list_syntax
[2] https://secure.php.net/manual/de/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.symmetric-array-destructuring

Comment: NOTE: This useful technique produces a different result than the accepted answer. The accepted answer puts the entire array into each variable. *This* answer puts first element into first variable, second into second, etc. So `$var1 = 1; $var2 = 2; ...` Especially useful for returning multiple values from a function - put the return values into an array, and extract them as shown.

Comment: So to initialize each of the left-side variables to an empty array, it would look like: [$var1, $var2, $var3] = [ [], [], [] ]

Comment: Although useful, it doesn't look as if the OP wanted to destruct an array, simply assign the same value to multiple vars at once.

Comment: Upvote because it's the answer I was looking for when I asked the question in the title. It's not the right answer to the OP, but maybe it's the right place to put the answer to the question which it _is_ the right answer to!

Answer (score 22):

```
$c = $b = $a;
```

is equivalent to

```
$b = $a;
$c = $b;
```

therefore:

```
$var1 = $var2 = $var3 = $var4=  $var5 = array();
```

Comment: Your answer is confusing
The equivalent should be:
$b = $a;
$c = $a;

Comment: `$x = [1,2]; $y = [5,6];` `$x[] = $y[] = 0;` according to your answer $x will become _[1,2,[5,6,0]]_ the actual result is **[1,2,0]** ie, `$c = $a;`

Comment: The example just above is not using assignment as is stated in the original example but an array push.  The return value for the array push is the value being pushed, not the array being pushed into.  When you do an assignment, the return value from the assignment is the assigned variable.

Or to put it another way, an array push returns the right side, an assignment returns the left side (which equals the right anyway).

So in your example, the right array push returns the zero being pushed to the left assignment.  You can see that the final value of `$y` also has the `0` pushed on.

Comment: @valiD I guess you are wrong in this case. PHP sets $b equals $a and $c equals $b. It passes the value step by step. So Miquel is right with his equivalent part. `$c =  1 + $b = $a = 1;` Makes $c equal 2 and not 1.

Answer (score 12):

I prefer to use the **list** function for this task. This is not really a function but a language construct, used to assign a list of variables in one operation.

`list( $var1, $var2, $var3 ) = array('coffee', 'brown', 'caffeine');`

For more information see the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php).

Comment: As with the newer square bracket notation [mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53081424/2129574), this does not answer the OP question.  Instead of copying the same value to all variables, this parses the individual values of the array.

Answer (score 9):

```
$var1 = $var2 = $var3 = $var4=  $var5 = array();
```

Comment: That's wrong. The result here is: All these vars gets the same value (that equals to `array()`). Th e solution is using of the `list()`. S. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50984039/2019043).