# In Javascript, is there a name for the following: variable = variable = value;

Tags: javascript, coding-style

Is there a name for this? Here's an example of what I'm trying to say:

```
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
i = j = 1;
```

So obviously both `i` and `j` are set to 1. But is there a name for this practice? Also, in terms of good coding standards, is this type of thing generally avoided? Can I also get an example or explanation of why it is/isn't good practice?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387247/in-javascript-is-chained-assignment-okay

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Daniel said, it's called chained assignment. It's generally avoided, because for some values (such as objects), the line `i = j = _something_` creates a reference from `i` to `j`. If you later change `j`, then `i` also changes.

```
var i = {};
var j = {};
i = j = {a:2};
j.a = 3; //Now, j.a === 3 AND i.a === 3
```

See this jsFiddle demo for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/jackwanders/a2XJw/1/

If you don't know what `i` and `j` are going to be, you could run into problems

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for. I could have sworn that I tried this once before and it skewed what I was trying to do, and this explains it. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it is called "assignment chaining".

We say that assignment is "right associative".  That means that

```
i = j = 1;
```

is equivalent to

```
i = (j = 1);
```

`j = 1` will assign the number `1` to `j` and then return the value of j (which is now `1`).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's referred to as "chained assignment" and sometimes as "multiple variable assignment". Also, you might want to look at the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257131/multiple-variable-assignment) question.