# PHP - Why is DateTime object copied by reference in my code?

Tags: php, datetime

Why in this code my DateTime object was copied by reference it seems?
Here's my code:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$dt1 = new \DateTime('2015-03-15');
$dt2 = $dt1;
$dt2 = $dt2->modify('-1 year');

echo $dt1->format('c') . PHP_EOL;
echo $dt2->format('c');

?>
```

I was expecting:

```
2015-03-15T00:00:00+00:00
2014-03-15T00:00:00+00:00
```

But I got this:

```
2014-03-15T00:00:00+00:00
2014-03-15T00:00:00+00:00
```

Comment: You need to use clone `$dt2 = clone $dt1;`

Comment: If you use the class `DateTimeImmutable` it will work, it behaves exactly the same as `DateTime` class except it never modifies itself but returns a new object instead.

Answer (score 8):

It's because of this line

```
$dt2 = $dt1;
```

Variables get copied, objects get referenced.

See this for an answer with examples - https://stackoverflow.com/a/6257203/1234502

You should be able to fix this with [clone](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)

Comment: `Variables get copied, objects get referenced`, not really precise

Comment: Really? I thought that this is what happens in php.

Comment: Yes, but "variables" and "objects" aren't different things. You should say value/raw types and objects (as written in the answers you mentioned)

Comment: You are correct, read what I read once more and realized it isn't stating what I meant, at all.

Comment: Instead of just saying "not really precise" maybe try be more helpful to explain *why* off the bat?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following text from PHP's [Objects and references page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php):

> As of PHP 5, an object variable doesn't contain the object itself as value anymore. It only contains an object identifier which allows object accessors to find the actual object.

Basically, your `$dt2 = $dt1;` is simply copying the object reference and not its contents; see the response by @lolka_bolka for the appropriate means by which to perform this task.