# PHP: what does a double assignment look like in longform?

Tags: php, ternary-operator, assignment-operator

I wasn't even sure how to Google this. How would this PHP statement be written longform?

```
$recentlyViewed = $products = $this->getRecentlyViewedProducts();
```

Optimizations like this make experts feel smart, and beginners feel really stupid. I'm pretty sure I understand what the outcome is, but maybe I'm wrong.

### A: Is this equivalent?

```
$products = $this->getRecentlyViewedProducts();
$recentlyViewed = ($products) ? true : false;
```

### B: Is this equivalent?

```
$products = $this->getRecentlyViewedProducts();
$recentlyViewed = $products;
```

### Which is right?

Via Twitter, seems B is equivalent.

### Public Service Announcement

Write glaringly simple code. Don't be clever.

Comment: `$products = $this->getRecentlyViewedProducts();
$recentlyViewed = $products;`

Comment: If you want to assign the `$this->getRecentlyViewedProducts()` if it's not empty you may do it this way:
`$recentlyViewed = $this->getRecentlyViewedProducts() ? : 'other_value';`
Here omitting second argument means that the first one will be assigned if it evaluates to true. Otherwise, the 'other_value' will be assigned. Have in mind that it will work only if the method returns empty array or null/false/0/empty string if there are no recently viewed. If it returns, e.g. a collection object it would evaluate to true, even if it's actually empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$recentlyViewed = $products = $this->getRecentlyViewedProducts();
```

And

```
$products = $this->getRecentlyViewedProducts();
$recentlyViewed = ($products) ? true : false;
```

> I think this is equivalent:

Nope its not equivalent.

Let's see the difference

```
$recentlyViewed = $products = range(1,10);
```

So if you `print_r` then the value'll be

```
print_r($recentlyViewed);
print_r($products);
```

This'll print two arrays from `[1,2,3,....10]` but the

```
$products = range(1,10);
$recentlyViewed = ($products) ? true : false;
```

So if you print the `$products` and `$recentlyViewed` then the result will  be the first'll print an `array` and the other one'll print `1`.

So whats the equivalent of

```
$recentlyViewed = $products = $this->getRecentlyViewedProducts();
```

will be

```
$products = $this->getRecentlyViewedProducts();
$recentlyViewed = $products;
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/mADet)

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent is this

```
$products = $this->getRecent();
$recentlyViewed = $products;
```

I'm not sure how a test for `$products` would make sense there as the double assignment does not return booleans.

See here the difference between raw types and objects.
[Are multiple variable assignments done by value or reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257131/are-multiple-variable-assignments-done-by-value-or-reference)

Comment: You're right about the double assignment. This is confusing for beginners because it's common to see non-explicit ternaries like: $x = $y === 1; That's a hard harder to understand than something explicit like: $x = ($y === 1) ? true : false; Hence my confusion with the above and not recognizing the assignment behaves differently than a comparison operator.

Comment: first of all there are no "ternaries" plural in PHP :) As far as I know there is only one ternary operator, the short-hand `if`,it's called ternary because it takes 3 operands, the condition and two results, one for `true` and one for `false`.

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

```
$recentlyViewed = $products = $this->getRecentlyViewedProducts();
```

what PHP does is that begging from the right hand and assigns most right value to the left side variable (if any). This value can be a const value (i.e. string or number), another variable or return value of a function (`$this->getRecentlyViewedProducts()` in this case). So here are steps:

- calculate return value of `(`$this->getRecentlyViewedProducts()`in this case)`
- assign calculated value to `$products`
- assign `$product` to `$recentlyViewed`

so if we assume your `getRecentlyViewedProducts` function returns 'Hello Brendan!', at the end of execution, both `$products` and `$recentlyViewed` would have same value.

In PHP, variable types are implicit and therefore you can use them directly in `if` statements like this:

`if($recentlyViewed)
{
    ...
}`

and in this case if `$recentlyViewed` is setted and its value `$recentlyViewed` is anything other that `0`, `false` or `null`, your `if` condition will satisfy.
It's very common to use non-boolean values in PHP as check conditions, anyway if you are using `$recentlyViewed` just as a flag, it's better to do this for the sake of code readability and memory optimization (attention that if your function returns for example a large string, copying its value in a separate variable to use it as just a flag is not a wise choice):

```
$recentlyViewed = $products ? true : false;
```

or

```
$recentlyViewed = $products ? 1 : 0;
```

althogh the result would not be different.